# Hide my Twitter followers

Tags: twitter, privacy, followers

For privacy reasons, I don't want everyone to be able to see who follows me on Twitter.
How to do?

I am OK with removing all of my followers if it is the only solution, but I hope there are more diplomatic solutions.

Comment: Yeah sorry that is a take all or take none solution. You are looking for a friend feature in a service that is meant for micro-blogging.

Comment: Consider using different accounts (e.g. one for business, one for personal)

Comment: @phwd: I ended up following your advice and using one public account + one private account. I ban friends who try to subscribe to my public account, and add them to the private one. Works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible to do for people following you, it is only possible to do for people you are following.